# How to use spacy's lemmatizer to get a word into basic form

Tags: python, nltk, spacy, lemmatization

I am new to spacy and I want to use its lemmatizer function, but I don't know how to use it, like I into strings of word, which will return the string with the basic form the words.

Examples:

- 'words'=> 'word'
- 'did' => 'do'

Thank you.

Comment: http://textminingonline.com/getting-started-with-spacy

Comment: https://spacy.io/docs

Comment: thank you, I have see this web before, but they didn't explain detail in it, ok, I will try the web code, thank you again.

Answer (score 77):

Previous answer is convoluted and can't be edited, so here's a more conventional one.

```
# make sure your downloaded the english model with "python -m spacy download en"

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

doc = nlp(u"Apples and oranges are similar. Boots and hippos aren't.")

for token in doc:
    print(token, token.lemma, token.lemma_)
```

Output:

```
Apples 6617 apples
and 512 and
oranges 7024 orange
are 536 be
similar 1447 similar
. 453 .
Boots 4622 boot
and 512 and
hippos 98365 hippo
are 536 be
n't 538 not
. 453 .
```

From the [official Lighting tour](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/lightning-tour)

Comment: Do you need to signify the text is unicode before passing it to `nlp`? See [here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/lightning-tour#examples-resources)

Comment: @PhilipO'Brien maybe with python 2 but I'm using python 3 here

Comment: Ah OK, with Python 2 I have to explicitly state it's unicode. Thanks! (I really should switch to 3!)

Comment: One problem with this is any pronouns are lemmatized to '-PRON-', which is confusing.  Why wouldn't it just keep the pronoun itself?

Comment: Search for '-PRON-' [here](https://nicschrading.com/project/Intro-to-NLP-with-spaCy/) to see a solution, but I think this should not be the default behavior.  It seems confusing.

Comment: Why does apples remain apples but other plurals get changed to the singular?

Answer (score 26):

If you want to use just the Lemmatizer, you can do that in the following way:

```
from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
from spacy.lang.en import LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES

lemmatizer = Lemmatizer(LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES)
lemmas = lemmatizer(u'ducks', u'NOUN')
print(lemmas)
```

Output

```
['duck']
```

**Update**

Since spacy version 2.2, LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, and LEMMA_RULES have been bundled into a [`Lookups`](https://spacy.io/api/lookups) Object:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

nlp.vocab.lookups
>>> <spacy.lookups.Lookups object at 0x7f89a59ea810>
nlp.vocab.lookups.tables
>>> ['lemma_lookup', 'lemma_rules', 'lemma_index', 'lemma_exc']
```

You can still use the lemmatizer directly with a word and a POS (part of speech) tag:

```
from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer, ADJ, NOUN, VERB

lemmatizer = nlp.vocab.morphology.lemmatizer
lemmatizer('ducks', NOUN)
>>> ['duck']
```

You can pass the POS tag as the imported constant like above or as string:

```
lemmatizer('ducks', 'NOUN')
>>> ['duck']
```

from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer, ADJ, NOUN, VERB

Comment: I tried your code, but I'm getting an error, ``` cannot import name 'LEMMA_INDEX' from 'spacy.lang.en'```

Answer (score 11):

**Code :**

```
import os
from spacy.en import English, LOCAL_DATA_DIR

data_dir = os.environ.get('SPACY_DATA', LOCAL_DATA_DIR)

nlp = English(data_dir=data_dir)

doc3 = nlp(u"this is spacy lemmatize testing. programming books are more better than others")

for token in doc3:
    print token, token.lemma, token.lemma_
```

**Output :**

```
this 496 this
is 488 be
spacy 173779 spacy
lemmatize 1510965 lemmatize
testing 2900 testing
. 419 .
programming 3408 programming
books 1011 book
are 488 be
more 529 more
better 615 better
than 555 than
others 871 others
```

Example Ref: [here](http://textminingonline.com/getting-started-with-spacy)

Comment: nlp = English(data_dir=data_dir) :  
data_dir = data_dir, what does this meaning, they looks same.

Comment: passing variable. English() method takes argument data_dir. So you pass "data_dir = local_variable_name". It can be also like,  
d_dir = os.environ.get('SPACY_DATA', LOCAL_DATA_DIR)
nlp = English(data_dir=d_dir)  
Its just basic python stuff.

Comment: Ok, I will a try these.

Comment: This gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.en'` in the current version (2.2).

Answer (score 10):

I use Spacy version 2.x

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['parser', 'ner'])
doc = nlp('did displaying words')
print (" ".join([token.lemma_ for token in doc]))
```

and the output :

```
do display word
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Use only tagger component is a good idea! This can sometimes make a big difference and improve loading speed.

Answer (score 2):

**To get a mapping between words and their lemmas** use this:

```
import spacy
# instantiate pipeline with any model of your choosing
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

words = "Those quickest and brownest foxes jumped over the laziest ones."

# only enable the needed pipeline components to speed up processing
with nlp.select_pipes(enable=['tok2vec', 'tagger', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer']):
    doc = nlp(words)

lemma_mapping = dict([(token.text, token.lemma_) 
                       for token in doc if token.is_punct==False])

print(lemma_mapping)
```

Output

```
{'Those': 'those',
 'quickest': 'quick',
 'and': 'and',
 'brownest': 'brown',
 'foxes': 'fox',
 'jumped': 'jump',
 'over': 'over',
 'the': 'the',
 'laziest': 'lazy',
 'ones': 'one'}
```

Answer (score -2):

I used:

```
import spacy

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
doc = nlp("did displaying words")
print(" ".join([token.lemma_ for token in doc]))
>>> do display word
```

But it returned

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I used:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

to get rid of error.