# How can get the base form of a word programmatically from the inflected form?

Tags: python, nlp

I want to find the base-form for input words in python

something like

```
get_base_form({running, best, eyes, moody})
--> run, good, eye, mood
```

A solution, that just deals with regular forms would be fine. But an answer, that also deals with irregular would be perfect.

If there is no library that does this, a web-service would be fine, too.

Comment: Did you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763007/how-to-use-spacy-lemmatizer-to-get-a-word-into-basic-form)?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: @php_nub_qq yes. "spacy" could work, but I don't think it's the only solution

Comment: google for "lemmatizing", not "stemming" - stems are not base forms of words - they are often not even words, but lemmas are. They depend on the Part Of Speech Tag of your word. For python, you can research spacy or nltk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SnowballStemmer from `nltk` natural language toolkit:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
print(stemmer.stem("generalized"))
print(stemmer.stem("generalization"))
```

output:

```
general
general
```

by the way, you can read nltk's documation @ https://www.nltk.org/